# How does one locate a .zshrc file?

Tags: shell, zsh, zshrc

I used [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) to install Z shell (zsh) 5.0.7 on my Mac.

For the life of me, .zshrc is nowhere to be found. It is not in ~. Is is not in */etc* or */etc/zshrc* as they suggest here: http://zshwiki.org/home/config/files

Am I supposed to create it myself?

Comment: no ide about mac. maybe there's a skeleton version in /etc/skel or something, but generally the ~/.zshrc is just to override defauls compiled into the shell or set at the system level. if you don't have one, it's not the end of the world - create one and start writing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sure. If it's not there already, create it yourself.

```
$ touch ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I lost way too much time on that !

Comment: You can just search on the web for "sample .zshrc" instead of writing your own from the scratch.

Comment: Where i should touch it?

Answer (score 3):

You can run the helper script [`zsh-newuser-install`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108136/run-the-zsh-first-use-wizard/108137#108137) from the prompt, and it will  walk you through the process to create an initial .zshrc in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

As [kyranjamie mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723293/how-does-one-locate-a-zshrc-file/26723348#26723348), you can create it using following command

```
$ touch ~/.zshrc
```

Example content of **.zshrc** file:

```
PATH=$PATH:/your_path_goes_here
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to find any file on a Unix-based system, you can try the command:

```
$ locate filename
```

It should list all the paths where the corresponding file exists.

Answer (score 0):

In Unix based systems, **touch** command followed by name will create an empty file in the present directory.

the modification and access time of each file is also updated with the use of touch command.

In your case, to create .zshrc file, you can use the touch command as :

```
$ touch ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: This comment does not add anything new on top of all the other `touch FILE` answers.